# disable layout for sfDoctrineGuardPlugin in Symfony

Tags: php, symfony1, symfony-1.4

How could I prevent mentioned plugin's login form from using default layout? I am aware of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610133/how-to-set-different-template-layout-for-different-modules-in-symfony), but that answer doesnt work for me. For starters, there's no signin module in modules dir, probably plugins handle it in different way, I dont know. Just learning symfony. Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to set a different layout, you need to add a module (just create it manually) called "sfGuardAuth". Inside the /config/ directory for that, change the layout in the view.yml like for any other module. This is explained in:

http://www.symfony-project.org/plugins/sfDoctrineGuardPlugin/4_0_0

... under section "Customize sfGuardAuth module actions".

However, if you want to "embed" your login form on another existing page, you could turn the login into a component - which means it uses the existing layout of the page it occurs in.

**Component action in a custom module:**

```
public function executeSigninLightbox(sfWebRequest $request)
{
    $class = sfConfig::get('app_sf_guard_plugin_signin_form', 'sfGuardFormSignin'); 
    $this->form = new $class();
}
```

... which like all components uses a partial as its view. The partial now has access to $form like a standard login page. The partial for this would be called "_signinLightbox".

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 2):

For now its not possible to set custom layout for some `sfGuardAuth` action via custom `view.yml`.
This is how I did it.
This is my `apps/backend/modules/sfGuardAuth/actions/actions.class.php`:

```
<?php

require_once(sfConfig::get('sf_plugins_dir').'/sfDoctrineGuardPlugin/modules/sfGuardAuth/lib/BasesfGuardAuthActions.class.php');

class sfGuardAuthActions extends BasesfGuardAuthActions
{
    public function preExecute()
    {
        $layout = $this->getActionName() == sfConfig::get('sf_login_action') ? 'sfGuardLayout' : $this->getLayout();
        $this->setLayout($layout);
    }
}
```